# I am attaching an App to a Product that has no proxies. Any caveats?

Tags: apigee

There are 3 App scenarios and questions that follow.

---

**Background**

Assume that all APIs except OAuth-ClientCredentials proxy are protected by Apigee's OAuth/VerifyAccessToken policy.

**App 1**

- Product A
- Product B

**App 2**

- Product B

**App 3**

- *No Products (achievable by deletion via [API](http://apigee.com/docs/ja/api/delete-api-product-developer-app-key-profile))*

**Product A**

- OAuth-ClientCredentials proxy (to generate token via HTTP Basic Auth)
- No resource paths

**Product B**

- *No API proxies*
- No resource paths

---

**Questions**

1. Does App 1 have access to all APIs (protected and non-protected) by
   nature of association with Product B?
2. Does App 2 have access to all APIs (protected and non-protected)? This notably includes access to OAuth-ClientCredentials proxy which is not listed in any Products.
3. Does App 3 have access to all APIs (protected and non-protected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does App 1 have access to all APIs (protected and non-protected) by
>      nature of association with Product B?
> 2. Does App 2 have access to all APIs (protected and non-protected)? This notably includes access to OAuth-ClientCredentials proxy which is
>      not listed in any Products.
> 3. Does App 3 have access to all APIs (protected and non-protected)?

The answer to all 3 question is **yes**.

1. **Yes** -- As a convenience for fast prototyping with OAuth integration, developers do not need to list/update a Product with new API proxies for inclusion in Apigee's OAuth system.
2. **Yes** -- Taking the App 1 test one step further, Product A is not even required for prototyping.
3. **Yes** -- This is an atypical case.  The UI does not allow an admin to delete all Products for a particular App.  An admin would need to delete via API.

***Also note that once you include 1 API proxy in a Product, the Product is locked down.  Thereafter, access is restricted to the API proxies specifically listed in that Product.***